# Can I upgrade my laptop's AMD processor to an i3?

Tags: cpu, processor-socket

I'm using an Acer® Aspire AS5253-BZ493 Notebook (LX.RD502.053).

Am I able to upgrade its processor to an i3 or i5?

- **Operating System**: Genuine Windows® 7 Home Premium 64-bit
- **Processor**: HD Internet Technology from AMD with AMD Dual-Core Processor C-50 (1.0GHz, 1MB L2 Cache)

Answer (score 4):

No, your laptop uses an AMD processor which will not let you upgrade to a Intel one due to incompatible chipsets.

Comment: Thats really it. Also, laptops arn't all that easy to upgrade. On the off chance you could, it would need to be very specific types of processors